# session authentication between ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, session

I'm wondering what the typical way storing a session would be, so that you could not just typing in www.website.com/inserter.php?this=whatever and insert something into a database.  Currently I do have a file which has the sole purpose of inserting into a database, and I'm wondering how to prevent unauthorized use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html) out, it is about ajax login to php and keep your session data page to page in php.

Answer (score 0):

I always just use a session class and store the user_id in the session and. I then create a function that checks to see if the persoI do all this with PHP only and it works great.